# Libraries for connecting node.js to odbc on Windows?

Tags: windows, node.js, ms-access, odbc

I'm looking for a library that allows node.js to connect to ODBC on windows.  All the libraries I have found thus far seem to work with UnixODBC but not windows, can someone please suggest a library that will work with Windows?

Comment: Although I haven't tried it yet, node-sharp suppoesedly enables .NET dll's to be called by node.js: https://github.com/anodejs/node-sharp

Comment: I guess ODBC is considered a pretty old technology...

Comment: I would use OLEDB in the .NET dll.

Comment: So here's what I had to do...I needed to connect the odbc data source as a Linked Server in SQL Server, and then connect to SQL Server with node.js and query the linked server from there.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Although the readme only mentions UnixODBC, this project: 
https://github.com/wankdanker/node-odbc 
will actually install and work on windows.

You can install it on windows with:

`npm install odbc`

but you will need the various requiements for building native modules on windows:

https://github.com/TooTallNate/node-gyp

Comment: For others, there is also: https://github.com/idobatter/node-win32ole which gives access to more than just odbc.

It ALSO requires node-gyp however.

Comment: You also need Python installed

Comment: Works for me. Side note: I have a 32bit driver on a 64bit machine and encountered [ERROR|IM014|Microsoft|ODBC Driver Manager|The specified DSN contains an architecture mismatch between the Driver and Application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21395492/error-im014-microsoftodbc-driver-manager-the-specified-dsn-contains-an-arc). Solution: Run the 32bit version of NodeJS

Comment: You'll likely need to rebuild odbc to work with your version of Electron. To do that, follow the steps here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45930921/293280