# NodeJS connect to paradox database

Tags: node.js, paradox

Does anyone know if there's any way to connect to a paradox database with node.js on windows ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd need an ODBC driver for node running on Windows. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13017024/libraries-for-connecting-node-js-to-odbc-on-windows?rq=1) might be of some help.