# Electron Native Addon: Version missmatch

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, electron, native

I am trying to create a simple example Native addon for Electron. However, keep running into this version miss match issue. I have .nvmrc files for both my electron project and the addon project (using node 7.4.0).

- Electron 1.6.7
- Node 7.4.0
- Nvm 0.33.2
- NPM 4.0.5

**The Error**

```html
App threw an error during load
Error: The module '/Users/mikepriest/source/Browser/exambrowser-electron/app/native/prebuilt/addon/build/Release/native_rt.node'
was compiled against a different Node.js version using
NODE_MODULE_VERSION 51. This version of Node.js requires
NODE_MODULE_VERSION 54. Please try re-compiling or re-installing
the module (for instance, using `npm rebuild` or`npm install`).
    at process.module.(anonymous function) [as dlopen] (ELECTRON_ASAR.js:173:20)
    at Object.Module._extensions..node (module.js:598:18)
    at Object.module.(anonymous function) [as .node] (ELECTRON_ASAR.js:173:20)
    at Module.load (module.js:488:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:447:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:439:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:498:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/mikepriest/source/Browser/exambrowser-electron/app/main.dev.js:20:10)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/mikepriest/source/Browser/exambrowser-electron/app/main.dev.js:217:3)
```

**Tried solutions**
 1. Tried using
        ./node_modules/.bin/electron-rebuild
 2. Tried rebuilding my addon
        nvm use 7.4.0
        npm rebuild

Still get the error.

Update: found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42616008/node-module-version-conflict-when-installing-modules-for-electron), but solution didn't work for me either.

Comment: This is more of a Java question than c++. If you tag this as Java then the Java folks might answer.

Comment: The Addon I have made is C++ and Electron is built with Node.js and C++