# Native node module for Electron project compiles against the wrong version of Node.js on Linux

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, electron, ubuntu-16.04

I am trying to install [this Electron project](https://github.com/codeforscience/sciencefair). It uses the two package.json structure and is written for Electron 1.7.2. All of the dependencies install fine and the [setup instructions](https://github.com/codeforscience/sciencefair#development) include running electron-rebuild, which also runs without complaining. However, when I run `npm run dev` an empty window opens and the following is in the console:

`` Uncaught Error: The module '[...]/sciencefair/app/node_modules/webworker-threads/build/Release/WebWorkerThreads.node'
was compiled against a different Node.js version using
NODE_MODULE_VERSION 51. This version of Node.js requires
NODE_MODULE_VERSION 54. Please try re-compiling or re-installing
the module (for instance, using `npm rebuild` or`npm install`).
        at process.module.(anonymous function) [as dlopen] (ELECTRON_ASAR.js:173:20)
    at Object.Module._extensions..node (module.js:598:18)
    at Object.module.(anonymous function) [as .node] (ELECTRON_ASAR.js:173:20)
    at Module.load (module.js:488:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:447:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:439:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:498:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at bindings (/[...]/sciencefair/app/node_modules/bindings/bindings.js:76:44)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/[...]/sciencefair/app/node_modules/webworker-threads/index.js:1:198) ``

I've tried installing the exact same version of Node.js that Electron 1.7.2 is targetting (7.9.0) but I get the same thing, with and without running `electron-rebuild`.

I'm a web guy and have no real Electron experience. System: Ubuntu LTS 16.04

Answer (score 0):

Following the longer answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42616008/node-module-version-conflict-when-installing-modules-for-electron) did it:

```
export npm_config_target=1.7.2
export npm_config_arch=x64
export npm_config_target_arch=x64
export npm_config_disturl=https://atom.io/download/electron
export npm_config_runtime=electron
export npm_config_build_from_source=true
HOME=~/.electron-gyp npm install
```