# Serial communication with arduino from electron-vue

Tags: vue.js, electron

my OS - Linux Ubuntu 16.04 and I have the desktop application made with [Electron-Vue](https://github.com/SimulatedGREG/electron-vue)

For example, I want to add button with function of sending data to arduino uno by serial port. But I cannot import **serialport** module to my Vue component. Also, I tried to use **serialport-electron** module, but result is the same. Is there any way to solve this problem? I think that my code is not important here, but if somebody will ask, I will attach it to this post. Thank you

Comment: What do you mean you can't import it?

Comment: @BertEvans, when I print import serialport from "serialport" I have an error:  build/Release/serialport.node'
was compiled against a different Node.js version using
NODE_MODULE_VERSION 57

Comment: Maybe this will help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42616008/node-module-version-conflict-when-installing-modules-for-electron

Comment: @BertEvans, when I run ./node_modules/.bin/electron-rebuild command, error comes

Answer (score 0):

If you were on windows this is how you would solve it

> Install windows build tools in your computer by running this in your powershell with administrator access

```
 npm install --global --production windows-build-tools
```

> or npm --add-python-to-path='true' --debug install --global windows-build-tools

```
 setx PYTHON "%USERPROFILE%\.windows-build-tools/python27/python.exe"

 set PYTHON
```

> set PYTHON helps you check if its set up correctly.
>
> This is not enough install electron rebuild globally in your project files

```
 npm install -g electron-prebuilt  
 npm install --save serialport
```

> We have to rebuild serialport to work with electron. To do this, we need to >install electron-rebuild:

```
 npm install --save-dev electron-rebuild
```

> The last step is to run electron-rebuild, once again, just in the root >directory of the app:

```
 ./node_modules/.bin/electron-rebuild -$(electron -v)
```

> import and use in your electron-vue project

```
<script>     
  const sp = require('serialport')
  export default {
    name: 'landing-page',
    methods: {},
    created () {
      sp.list(function (error, ports) {
        if (error) {
          console.log(error)
        } else {
          console.log(ports)
        }
      })
    }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: No, I am using linux. Thank you for your answer